# html ahref(pointing to cloud) not opening in the same frame and goes to a new window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html5 application with screen divided in 2 parts.

Left part has few links and on click of the link the resultant should open in the right side frame of the same window.

It is working fine for ahref link pointing to another html.
But it is not working for the ahref pointing to link on cloud.

Sample link of the cloud is [here](https://apps.na.collabserv.com/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/We76042abfe70_4f07_9b6a_219689638736/page/Welcome%20to%20Integrated%20project%20planning%20and%20forecasting).

Please find the below screenshots for more understanding.

[image: I clicked the link and the loginpage opens in the frame itself.After givng the login credentials the complete html applicaiton disapperas and the cloud link is occupying the whole window as below]

[html applciation left side links and right side frame everthing disappears and finally the link opned in the full window][2]

Comment: Please refer [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can debug the code to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

seems while launching the cloud url it is using IFRAME(based on the window properties) which we cant control from the code.